# Replacing zeroes with NA for values preceding non-zero

Tags: r

I'm new to R and have been struggling with the following for a while now so I was hoping someone would be able to help me out.

The sample data represents stock price returns (each row is a monthly period). The real data set is much bigger and is structured like the input below:

**Input:**

```
stock1 <- c(0.01, -0.02, 0.01, 0.05, 0.04, -0.02)
stock2 <- c(0, 0, 0.02, 0.04, -0.03, 0.02)
stock3 <- c(0, 0, 0.02, 0, -0.01, 0.03)
stock4 <- c(0, -0.02, 0.01, 0, 0, -0.02)
df <- cbind(stock1,stock2,stock3,stock4)

     stock1 stock2 stock3 stock4
[1,]   0.01   0.00   0.00   0.00
[2,]  -0.02   0.00   0.00  -0.02
[3,]   0.01   0.02   0.02   0.01
[4,]   0.05   0.04   0.00   0.00
[5,]   0.04  -0.03  -0.01   0.00
[6,]  -0.02   0.02   0.03  -0.02
```

Any zeroes that precedes a non-zero for a given stock represents missing data as opposed to a return of zero for the period. I would like to set these values as NA so the output I would like to achieve is the following:

**Desired Output:**

```
stock1 <- c(0.01, -0.02, 0.01, 0.05, 0.04, -0.02)
stock2 <- c(NA, NA, 0.02, 0.04, -0.03, 0.02)
stock3 <- c(NA, NA, 0.02, 0, -0.01, 0.03)
stock4 <- c(NA, -0.02, 0.01, 0, 0, -0.02)
df <- cbind(stock1,stock2,stock3,stock4)

     stock1 stock2 stock3 stock4
[1,]   0.01     NA     NA     NA
[2,]  -0.02     NA     NA  -0.02
[3,]   0.01   0.02   0.02   0.01
[4,]   0.05   0.04   0.00   0.00
[5,]   0.04  -0.03  -0.01   0.00
[6,]  -0.02   0.02   0.03  -0.02
```

I've tried a few things but they only seem to work for a single vector as opposed to a data set with multiple columns. I've tried using lapply to get around this but haven't had any luck so far. The closest I've gotten is shown below.

My single vector solution:

```
stock1[1:min(which(stock1!=0))-1 <- NA
```

My multiple vector solution which *does not work*:

```
lapply(df,function(x) x[1:min(which(x!=0))-1 <- NA]
```

Would greatly appreciate any guidance! Thanks!

Comment: Is it so that only the first, leading zeros should be changed? That means, if e.g. `stock1 <- c(0.01, -0.02, 0.01, 0, 0, -0.02)` you also want to keep them as 0, although there are two consecutive zeros? In your example, you have only single 0 in other places but not two consecutive ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three issues.  First, writing:

```
df <- cbind(stock1,stock2,stock3,stock4)
```

doesn't create a data frame.  It creates a matrix.  This is an issue when you try to use `lapply`, which will operate over the columns of a *data frame* but over the elements of a *matrix*.  Instead, you should write:

```
df <- data.frame(stock1,stock2,stock3,stock4)
```

Second, the function you're using in `lapply` needs to return the modified vector.  Otherwise, the return value will be something unexpected (in this case, the assignment will return a single `NA`, and the `lapply` will return a data frame of one row of `NA`s instead of the data frame you want).

Third, you need to take care with `1:n` when `n` can be zero (i.e., when the first stock quote is non-zero) because `1:0` gives the sequence `c(1,0)` instead of an empty sequence.  (This is arguably one of R's stupidest features.)

Therefore, the following will give you what you want:

```
stock1 <- c(0.01, -0.02, 0.01, 0.05, 0.04, -0.02)
stock2 <- c(0, 0, 0.02, 0.04, -0.03, 0.02)
stock3 <- c(0, 0, 0.02, 0, -0.01, 0.03)
stock4 <- c(0, -0.02, 0.01, 0, 0, -0.02)
df <- data.frame(stock1,stock2,stock3,stock4)

as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {
    n <- min(which(x != 0)) - 1
    if (n > 0)
        x[1:n] <- NA
    x
}))
```

The output is as expected:

```
  stock1 stock2 stock3 stock4
1   0.01     NA     NA     NA
2  -0.02     NA     NA  -0.02
3   0.01   0.02   0.02   0.01
4   0.05   0.04   0.00   0.00
5   0.04  -0.03  -0.01   0.00
6  -0.02   0.02   0.03  -0.02
```

*Update:*  As @Daniel_Fischer notes, there's a clever trick to avoid the `1:0` problem.  You can instead write:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {
    n <- min(which(x != 0)) - 1
    x[0:n] <- NA    # use 0:n instead of 1:n
    x
}))
```

This takes advantage of the fact that R ignores zeros in this type of indexing operation, so:

```
x[0:0] <- NA    # same as x[0] <- NA and does nothing
x[0:1] <- NA    # same as x[1] <- NA
x[0:2] <- NA    # same as x[1:2] <- NA, etc.
```

Comment: Oh, I see that @Daniel_Fischer has a nice workaround for the `n > 0` issue.  If you do `x[0:n] <- NA`, that will work whether `n` is zero or non-zero, so you can skip the `if` statement, too.

Comment: Thanks so much, really appreciate the help and prompt response! I'm still trying to get my head around the subtle but important differences between various "data structures" so thanks for pointing out the data.frame and as.data.frame functions too!

Answer (score 4):

This might be not the most elegant way, but I think it works

```
changeValues <- function(x){
   place <- min(which(diff(c(0,cumsum(x==0)))==0))-1;
   x[0:place] <- NA
   x
}

apply(df,2,changeValues)
```

EDIT: Some brief explanation to the function: First I create a vector that increases at each position where is a zero in your column, then I check at which position this vector does not increase (=that means, there are not two zeros next to each other) and then I still take the minimum of that and make sure that these are only leading zeros (so that not values from within the matrix are changed)

Comment: Okay, it was too early here, so my answer is certainly over-complicating things and `min(which(x!=0))-1` is the shorter way to get the `place`...

Answer (score 3):

```
stock1 <- c(0.01, -0.02, 0.01, 0.05, 0.04, -0.02)
stock2 <- c(0, 0, 0.02, 0.04, -0.03, 0.02)
stock3 <- c(0, 0, 0.02, 0, -0.01, 0.03)
stock4 <- c(0, -0.02, 0.01, 0, 0, -0.02)
df <- data.frame(stock1,stock2,stock3,stock4) #the following function only works if df is actually a data.frame

df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) {ifelse(cumsum(x) == 0 & x == 0, NA, x)})

df

  stock1 stock2 stock3 stock4
1   0.01     NA     NA     NA
2  -0.02     NA     NA  -0.02
3   0.01   0.02   0.02   0.01
4   0.05   0.04   0.00   0.00
5   0.04  -0.03  -0.01   0.00
6  -0.02   0.02   0.03  -0.02
```

Some explanation: first check for each cell whether the cumulative `colSum` ánd the current cell are equal to `0`. If so, return `NA`, else the original value. The brackets behind `df` make sure the `lapply` function returns a `dataframe` again that is assigned to `df`.

Also, if you don't really need df to be a dataframe, this works as well:

```
df <- cbind(stock1,stock2,stock3,stock4)
apply(df, 2, function(x) {ifelse(cumsum(x) == 0 & x == 0, NA, x)})
```